# External keyboard behaviour: "I replaced by Ï and so on

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-2

When trying to write using an external (USB) keyboard, any combination of [(speech marks)(letter)] results in conversion of the character pair to the umlaut version, if it exists (if there is no version, nothing happens). Same issue happens when trying to use a Bluetooth keyboard. Turning off auto-punctuate/correct makes no difference. This issue doe not exist when using the onscreen keyboard.

This appears to be global; anywhere I type that kind of thing I get that behavior.

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note II running 4.1.2, not rooted.

I have done some searching, but have not found this issue mentioned so far anywhere, any ideas?